# Android 10 page transition

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create Android 10 like page transition in my app for all devices(including sdk versions below 29).

I know that in Flutter we can build our own custom page transition animations, but I have no idea how to have that zoom effect that devices with Android 10 have.

So far

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Route zoomTransitionRoute(Widget child) {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnim) {
        return ScaleTransition(
          scale: animation,
          child: child,
        );
      },
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnim, child) {
        var begin = Offset(0.0, 0.1);
        var end = Offset(0.0, 0.0);

        var curve = Curves.ease;
        var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end);
        var curvedAnim = CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: curve);
        return SlideTransition(
          position: tween.animate(curvedAnim),
          child: child,
        );
      },
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));
}
```

This does *NOT* look like anything I want. Can anyone help me out?

**Edit**

This is what I want to achieve

[image]

Notice how the parent page zooms a little then the child page also zooms from a scale of almost `.9`

Comment: could you show us a example gif for what you want to achieve?

Comment: @yahyaparvar hey check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to use inbuilt `PageTransitionsTheme` to solve this.

In the parent `MaterialApp` ,

```dart
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: lightTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: RegisterPage(),
    );
```

The `lightTheme` and `darkTheme` can have a `pageTransitionsTheme` attribute,

```dart
ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
  //...
  pageTransitionsTheme: myPageTransitionsTheme,
  //...
);
```

And the `myPageTransitionsTheme` is initialized like,

```dart
PageTransitionsTheme pageTransitionsTheme = PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
  TargetPlatform.android: ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder(),
  TargetPlatform.iOS: ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder()
});
```

Tested on both iOS and Android, working!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [page_trasition](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition)

Because there is various transitions effect,also here is available that you want.

```
Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.fade, child: DetailScreen()));
```

Also you can directly use fade transition(you can change this by your requirement).like this

```
Navigator.push( context, 
PageRouteBuilder(
 pageBuilder: (c, a1, a2) => Page2(), 
  transitionsBuilder: (c, anim, a2, child) => 
   FadeTransition(opacity: anim, child: child), 
   transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 
   2000),
 ),
 );
```

And more details,check out this.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation

Comment: No, zoom transition. Not fade. It's a subtle transition where both the parent and the child zoom out. Did u read the complete question?

Comment: Yes,that why I suggest page_transition library.all the transition that I know,I suggested.

Comment: That page_transition link is showing a 404 error and the cookbook is where I got the current code from, it doesn't explain how to animate the parent page. Please check the page_transition link

Comment: I just searched for page_transition, that does NOT contain what I need